# Force evaluation with deparse in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, first-class-functions

I have a function that produces a function:

```
fun1 <- function (x)
    return (function() x)
```

By the time a function is produced, the value of `x` is already basically a constant:

```
fun2 <- fun1 ("a")
```

However, when I have `fun2` printed, it won't show the actual value, it only shows `"x"` even though it is by now obsolete:

```
> fun2
function() x
<environment: 0x55a9f94f9fc8>
```

How can I force the evaluation of `x` so that `fun2` gets printed as

```
function() "a"
```

or however it was produced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to resort to `deparse` here. You can write the evaluated value of x into the body of the newly created function:

```r
fun1 <- function (x){
  f <- function() x
  body(f) <- x
  f
}
```

So that:

```r
fun1("a")
#> function () 
#> "a"
#> <environment: 0x00000146d0449dd8>
```

and

```
f <- fun1("a")
f()
#> [1] "a"
```

**EDIT**

If you wanted `f` to take an argument you could do:

```r
fun1 <- function (x){
  f <- function(y) y + x
  body(f)[[3]] <- x
  f
}
```

so that

```r
fun1(3)
#> function (y) 
#> y + 3
#> <environment: 0x00000146d4b702a0>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that my minimal example was too minimal. I'd like `f` to take an argument, and I'd like to be able to use that argument inside the body of `f`. I've only managed to do it by enclosing the body of `f` in an `expression`, but then I'm back to square one. Say I'd like `f` to be `function(y) y+x`, and then `fun1(1)` to be printed as `function(y) y+1`.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot!
If you're very pedantic, `y` is missing from the declaration of `f` inside `fun1`.

Comment: @KamilS. I _am_ very pedantic. Now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This substitutes all instances of `x` in the body of `fun`.  In the example `fun1` has one argument but it would continue to work with multiple `fun1` arguments used in `fun` substituting them all into `fun`.  We have also set the environment of `fun` to the environment in the caller of `fun1` allowing the caller to change that by specifying `envir` if needed.

```
fun1 <- function (x, envir = parent.frame()) {
    fun <- function() x
    body(fun) <- do.call("substitute", list(body(fun)))
    environment(fun) <- envir
    fun
}

fun2 <- fun1("a")
fun2
## function () 
## "a"

environment(fun2)
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Comment: Thank you. This would have been more useful as it's more general but when I use something like `tmp[1]` inside `fun`, this puts the entire `tmp` into `fun` and just adds `[1]` at the end. But don't trouble yourself, I only have two elements to replace so it's not a problem doing it manually one by one like in Allan's solution.